# Different actions based on response status code in Redux-Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying out Redux-Toolkit and I'm really liking how concise it is but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to read server response status code and dispatch different actions based on that.
For instance, I'm sending a sign up request to an API

```
export const registerRequest = createAsyncThunk(
  'register/registerRequest',
  async (userInfo: RegisterInfo) => {
    const { firstname, lastname, email, password } = userInfo

    const { data } = await axios.post('url/users/create', {
      firstname,
      lastname,
      email,
      password,
    })
    return data
  }
)
```

I may receive different types of errors but all of them are handled by a single case in my slice

```
builder.addCase(registerRequest.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.error = action.error
    })
```

What is the right way to check for a status code and dispatch corresponding action with Redux-Toolkit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you'd want to handle the error in the `actionCreator` of `createAsyncThunk`. Being that you're using TS, you'll want to use `rejectWithValue` so that you can actually get types for the error interface. There are a few examples in the Usage with TypeScript docs here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk. If you have multiple known error response formats, I'd recommend adding type guards for those and introduce a utility helper for your reducer(s) because you'll always check those in the rejected case (`registerRequest.rejected` in this example) when using `createAsyncThunk`.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful